# How to set default value in dropdown

Tags: yii

i have a dropdown here in yii that looks like this:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'is_enabled', 
array('0'=>'No', '1'=>'Yes'), array('id'=>'new-sys-user-is_enabled',));?>
```

the problem with this is that it shows the 'No' because it has the 0 key. I would like to show the 'Yes' by default. What is the work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out if this works for you: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11748-dropdownlist-selected-option/

EDIT: Copying the relevant part:

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'sex',array('1'=>'men','2'=>'women'), array('options' => array('2'=>array('selected'=>true))));
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try like this ...

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'is_enabled', array('1'=>'Yes', '0'=>'No'), array('id'=>'new-sys-user-is_enabled',));?>
```

The value you want to keep default value, then keep first in array too.

Thanks